# How to dual boot other OS in Ubuntu without having access to boot menu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, wubi

I installed ubuntu 14.04 in my laptop a year back.
and a few months before the inbuilt display of the laptop got destroyed in an accident. But the other parts were working fine. so I connected my laptop to a external display device and I started to work on it.

The problem is that the external display is controlled by the Ubuntu OS and not the mother board. so when I attempt to install other distributions of Linux. I am not able to see the boot menu, since the display comes only when ubuntu turns on.

I've also tried VMs but they are not fast and not efficient. I am literally stuck with ubuntu.

Is their a way to dual boot my PC with other OS's without boot menu (that is via ubuntu itself, like there is wubi for windows) so that  I can change the default OS of the laptop using grub editor in Linux

I want Windows also in my laptop so preferably a solution for that would be even more better

Comment: We don't support Windows and non-Ubuntu distros here, also, I don't think there is a way to fix broken hardware with Ubuntu. Consider replacing the busted screen.

Answer (score 2):

A typical dual-boot configuration presents a menu of choices generated by a program like GRUB. These programs operate through the firmware (BIOS or EFI/UEFI), and so are dependent on its features. If your laptop's display is broken and if the firmware works only with the laptop's built-in display (as is common), then you will not get these tools to work with an external display. I know of no way around this rule. You might be able to boot "blind" by hitting the down-arrow key (or whatever) to switch boot options and just hope you get the right one.

That said, you may be able to set the boot option in an OS. For instance, if you've got Ubuntu and Windows installed, you could, in principle, adjust the GRUB default boot option while in one OS to boot the other OS the next time you boot. (This is controlled via the `set default` line in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.) There are some important caveats to this approach, though:

- Ubuntu stores its GRUB configuration file in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. You'd need to edit this file from Windows, which means using a Windows filesystem driver for ext4fs (or whatever filesystem holds that file).
- If you start with the computer off and want to boot OS A, but if it's currently configured to boot OS B, you'd need to boot OS B, reconfigure GRUB, and then reboot into OS A. This is obviously more awkward than choosing the OS to boot before booting any OS.
- If GRUB were to become badly misconfigured, you might lose the ability to boot anything, and repairing it would be a hassle. You might need to move the hard disk to another computer to do the necessary work.
- Given your current state, I'm not sure exactly how you'd boot the Windows installation medium. I suspect you could create a GRUB entry to do this, but I don't know exactly what it would look like. (It would probably depend on whether you're booting in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode or in EFI/UEFI mode.)
- I have no idea if the Windows installer would come up on the internal display only, the external display only, or on both displays. If the Windows installer ran only on the internal display, you wouldn't be able to install it.
- If you run into problems installing Windows, you might be able to use a virtual machine pointed at the whole-disk device or move the hard disk to another computer for installation, but these approaches carry their own risks and might not work acceptably well.

You could do similar things with other boot managers, not just GRUB; but the details of reconfiguring the boot manager vary. Of particular note is EFI-based computers, which have a built-in boot manager that can be configured via the Ubuntu `efibootmgr` tool, the standard Windows `bcdedit` tool, or the third-party GUI Windows [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) tool. I'd recommend using the EFI boot manager, rather than reconfiguring GRUB, to control the boot process on an EFI-based computer. To determine whether your computer is EFI-based, look for a directory called `/sys/firmware/efi` in Ubuntu. If that directory is present, your computer is EFI-based; if it's absent, you've booted in BIOS mode.

Speaking more broadly, IMHO you should look into either fixing your laptop's display or buying a new laptop. You may be able to find a replacement display (or whatever components are broken) for a decent price on eBay or the like. The hassles and risks of dual-booting "blind" are significant enough that I'd be reluctant to undertake them, particularly since an error might prove to be difficult to repair.